# Tkinter incremental counter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get the below method to incrementally subtract the number which is displayed as the text in the button, but cannot get it to update below 4.

```
def waterclick(watercount = 5):
    water = watercount - 1
    waterlabel.config(text = water)
    print(water)
```

full code:

```
# importing whole module
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()

#name of the program
label = ttk.Label(root, text = '.0.')
label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
label.config(text = "Howdy Tkinter")
label.config(foreground = 'white', background = 'black', font = ('impact', 14))

#increments water count by -1
def waterclick(watercount = 5):
    water = watercount - 1
    waterlabel.config(text = water)
    print(water)

#water button
waterlabel = ttk.Button(root, text = 5, command = waterclick)
waterlabel.grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 2)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because your function does not change the value of `watercount` which is the name of a function argument. The simplest fix is to use a global variable. That approach would be like this:

```
# importing whole module
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()

#name of the program
label = ttk.Label(root, text = '.0.')
label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
label.config(text = "Howdy Tkinter")
label.config(foreground = 'white', background = 'black', font = ('impact', 14))

#increments water count by -1
def waterclick():
    global watercount
    watercount -= 1  # Update value of global variable.
    waterlabel.config(text=watercount)
    print(watercount)

#Define global variable.
watercount = 5

#water button
waterlabel = ttk.Button(root, text = 5, command = waterclick)
waterlabel.grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 2)

mainloop()
```

A slightly better way to do it would be to use an instance of a tkinter [`IntVar`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201031100214id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) class and make it the `Label`'s `textvariable`, that way the label will get updated automatically everytime the `IntVar`'s value is changed.

```
# importing whole module
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()

#name of the program
label = ttk.Label(root, text = '.0.')
label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
label.config(text = "Howdy Tkinter")
label.config(foreground = 'white', background = 'black', font = ('impact', 14))

#increments water count by -1
def waterclick():
    watercount.set(watercount.get()-1)  # Update value of tkinter variable.
    print(watercount.get())

#Define tkinter Variable.
watercount = IntVar(value=5)

#water button
waterlabel = ttk.Button(root, textvariable = watercount, command = waterclick)
waterlabel.grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 2)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always passing the same number to your `waterclick` function, so it always substracts 1 from 5, hence you get 4 as a result.

The way to solve this is to actually *read* the number that you are displaying in the text each time you call `waterclick` and substract it from that number.

To get the current number displayed in your button you can use `waterlabel['text']`, as you would do with any other property in Tkinter.

Your code would end up like this:

```
#increments water count by -1
def waterclick():
    water = waterlabel['text'] - 1
    waterlabel.config(text = water)
    print(water)

#water button
waterlabel = ttk.Button(root, text = 5, command = waterclick)
waterlabel.grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# importing whole module
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()

#name of the program
label = ttk.Label(root, text = '.0.')
label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
label.config(text = "Howdy Tkinter")
label.config(foreground = 'white', background = 'black', font = ('impact', 14))

#increments water count by -1
def waterclick():
    water = waterlabel.cget("text") - 1
    waterlabel.config(text = water)
    print(water)

#water button
waterlabel = ttk.Button(root, text = 5, command = waterclick)
waterlabel.grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 2)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).